# When message will be stored in journal storage in Artemis

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.19.1. I went through the documentation of persistence in Artemis -
With respect to that :

1. When (at what stage) data is stored in journal files?
2. Size of storage used depends on what? the number of records OR something else?

I have an Artemis implementation with shared storage of 500 GB. With an average message
size of 2-5 KB, my 500 GB storage is getting full with only 60K messages stuck in the queue. Is this expected behavior?

Contradictory to this my installation worked fine when there were 200K messages in the Queue. The only difference was 60K messages mentioned in the previous scenario were completely stuck (i.e. 0 dequeue rate) whereas with the 2nd scenario of 200k messages dequeue rate was slow (i.e. 6 TPS).

When, only with 60K messages my storage of 500 GB was full, Artemis completely stopped accepting new messages I could see below log -

````
17:25:22,436 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222210: Free storage space is at 53.5GB of 536.9GB total. Usage rate is 90.0% which is beyond the configured <max-disk-usage>. System will start blocking producers.

17:25:22,514 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222038: Starting paging on address '<----->'; size is currently: 1,857 bytes; max-size-bytes: -1; global-size-bytes: 73,239,446```
````

Comment: There's too many questions here. I understand they're all related, but there's a handful of distinct questions which means your question is liable to be closed. You need to focus on an individual issue.